# What does Chowla's cosine problem actually ask to find?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, intuition, conjectures, open-problem

The problem according to [this description](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/op/chowlas_cosine_problem) is:

> Let $ A \subseteq {\mathbb N} $ be a set of $ n $ positive integers and set $m(A) = - \min_x \sum_{a \in A} \cos(ax).$
>
> What is $ m(n) = \min_A m(A) $?

What baffles me is how function $m$ first takes a set $A$ as an argument, then takes number $n$ as an argument, all in the same equation. What's more, while there's a need to minimize over $x$, the second equation asks to minimize also over $A$. Are we just allowed to pick any $A$ of $n$ elements and any real $x$ we want?

Could someone, please, clarify the ambiguous use of $m$ and provide an example to show some intuition behind the statement of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find it helpful to imagine these minimax type problems as a game.  For each $n$, we can imagine the following procedure:

1. You pick a set of $n$ integers
2. I pick a value of $x$,

The score of the game is the value of $\sum (-\cos(ax))$.  I'm trying to maximize the score, you're trying to minimize it.

No matter what set you pick, I can always score at least $0$ -- if I just choose a random $x$ between $0$ and $2\pi$, then on average $\cos(ax)$ will be $0$.  So the average score if I played completely at random would be $0$.  But this is just an average.  I'm allowed to pick whatever $x$ I want, so I can look at your choice of $A$, observe how the sum varies with $x$, and choose accordingly.  So in practice I can always score something positive.

Your strategy is to minimize the benefit I can get from choosing $x$ after you choose $A$-- you're looking for a choice of $A$ so that the sum doesn't vary too much with $x$, and the maximum isn't too large.

The Chowla problem is asking for the score of this game when you and I both play optimally

Comment: After some reflection on your explanation I like to imagine the score as a curve whose shape is defined by A and where we choose x to find the highest point on that curve. We then optimize A to makes the highest points of the curve be as low as possible. I think now I get the problem statement and why the equations are written the way they are! Thanks! (I will give it some time and then will accept as the answer)